# Adding variable number of layers with associated buffer distances with ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, buffer

I am using **ArcGIS Pro 2.7.2**

I am not an experienced python programmer. My goal is that the user can select a **various number of layers** in the python tool and **specify different buffer distances for each**. I imagine it visually so that there are two columns:

Column A: Upload layer
Column B: Individual buffer distance in m

This process can be carried out until the user has specified all layers. This is important as it is currently not known how many layers are needed. Already thought about python dictionary but I do not know if this works for this case.

Finally, the buffered layers have to be loaded into a GDB.

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env 
env.workspace = "file_path"
env.overwriteOutput = True 
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
bufdist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
for fc in fcs: 
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, OutputName, bufdist,"FULL", "ROUND", "LIST", "Distance")
```

Comment: import arcpy
from arcpy import env 
env.workspace = "file_path"
env.overwriteOutput = True
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
bufdist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, OutputName, bufdist,"FULL", "ROUND", "LIST", "Distance")

Comment: I still need a loop here, but I dont know how to manage it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to explore the helpfile and read up on what is referred to as a [python toolbox](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm). This will allow you to build the tool interface that will allow your users to select multiple layers and assign buffer distances to each layer. You need to define what is called a [ValueTable](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E2BAA5D4440D41D6AAB948922186905A).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in my solution:

```
import arcpy
import ConversionUtils

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/path"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
in_features = ConversionUtils.gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_features = ConversionUtils.SplitMultiInputs(in_features)
in_dist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
in_dist = ConversionUtils.SplitMultiInputs(in_dist)
for i in range(0, len(in_features)):
    Tmpfc = in_features[i]
    Tmpdist = in_dist[i]
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Tmpfc, Tmpfc+"Buffer", Tmpdist)
```